# Why is the space still there for a hidden EditText field in my Android layout?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a dynamic form input and sometimes the fields are hidden. But the layout still shows the empty space when I set it to invisible in onCreateView method. I want all the fields to move up if one of them is hidden.

`binding.vendorinvoice.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Here's my layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".activity.NewReceipt.NewReceiptReceiptHeader">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/projectnumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Project Number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/projectsequence"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Project sequence number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vendor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Vendor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vendorinvoice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Vendor Invoice number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/carrier"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Carrier" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/carriertrackingnumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Carrier tracking number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the result. what is the blank space there under Vendor??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead of `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` to avoid the blank space that is left.

Making the view `INVISIBLE` makes the view utilize the space that it was assigned to occupy while `GONE` will make the view behave as if it was not even put in the layout - it won't occupy any space.

Comment: so simple, makes perfect sense